# list of tuple of string to return in list in python

Tags: python, string, list

write a function which takes a string in the format given returns a list in given below format

```
input:  "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"
o/p: 
(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)
```

i have written the below code but not getting proper output:

```
def convertor(string):
    result = (string.split("  "))[0]
    return result


string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"

print(convertor(string1.replace("[","").replace("]","")))
```

Comment: If it's not possible to import any built-in library, please specify it in the question =)

Comment: use `eval(string1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
arr = ast.literal_eval("[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]")
for ele in arr:
    print(ele)
```

**Output**

```
(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)
```

Comment: Thank you ... but can we get without using that literal_eval() function
 i need output without using any built-in function

Comment: well `split,regex,replace` anything you do are built-ins. How can you do something without using buitins?

Comment: yes, you are correct but need that output without using eval() or literal_eva(), so is it possible to get that answer without using those function ... any suggetion

Comment: even i have written the below code using eval()---


def converter(string):
    return eval(string)
res= converter("[(694,104),(153,236),(201,106),(601,427)]")
print(res)

Comment: the code which you have written its returning the string format but i need that result in list .

Comment: `arr` is actually a list, you  can do a `type(arr)`

Comment: def convertor(string):
    result = (string.split("  "))[0]
    return result


string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"

print(convertor(string1.replace("[","").replace("]","")))


current output i am getting --(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)

but i need in the below format , i cant use ant module or built in only i can use string built in so kindly tell where i need to do the modification

output format which i needed:-
(694, 104) 
(153, 236) 
(201, 106)
 (601, 427)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
def convertor(string):
    return ast.literal_eval(string)

string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"
print(convertor(string1))
```

Comment: but if am using print(type(string)    i am getting <type 'str'>

Comment: i cant use any module or built in , only i can use string built in function

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that would be using `eval` (you don't need to import anything):

```py
eval(string1)
# -> [(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]
```

But, if you really want to use just `str` and `list` methods:

```py
def convertor(string):
    result = string.strip('[)]').split('), ')
    result = [s+')' for s in result]
    return result

string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"
print(convertor(string1))
# -> ['(694, 104)', '(153, 236)', '(201, 106)', '(601, 427)']
```

To reproduce the exact output:

```py
for item in convertor(string1):
    print(item)
```

```
(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)
```